# Parse In App Purchase Restore Functionality

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

My app was reject by Apple for not having a Restore fucntion for In-App-Purchasing.

I am using the Parse implementation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#in-app-purchases) which allows for restoring purchases if user has made a previous purchase by means of a Alert controller with a restore option displayed when user selects the purchase button.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the Restore option via ALert controller enough to satisfy the Apple guideline?
2. If not, is there a function in the Parse In App Purchase API that allows for restoring by the click of a button? As I could not find one in the docs.

Thansk In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden in the depths of the documentation is:

```
 PFPurchase.restore();
```

Which executes the block in the observer if a purchase has been made -

```
PFPurchase.addObserverForProduct("purchases.cases", block: { (transaction : SKPaymentTransaction!) -> Void in
            //set boolean to user defaults when in app p[urcahse is made, access agian in Tablevoew to relase cases

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();

            userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "inAppPurchaseMade");

            userDefaults.synchronize();

        })


        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html) might be helpful

and the other thing yes apple have their restore `UIAlertController` you don't need to add by yourself you have to just write the restore handling code and button.

```
//inside of an IBaction
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];


// Then this is called
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    NSLog(@"%@",queue );
    NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);  

    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
        NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);
        // here put an if/then statement to write files based on previously purchased items
        // example if ([productID isEqualToString: @"youruniqueproductidentifier]){write files} else { nslog sorry}
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I no if there is example code available in swift?

Comment: https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/swift-storekit-in-app-purchases

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial
both are in swift and vote up if answer is helpful and mark as correct :)